# не может преобразовать выражение` System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet <string>' в введите `System.Collections.Generic.IList <string>

Tags: c#

В этом фрагменте вылетает ошибка

```
'public string CalcGroupedDevicesKey(GroupedDevices group) 
    {
        return StringHelper.Join(",",group);
    }'
```

> не может преобразовать выражение`System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet <string>' в введите`System.Collections.Generic.IList

Join использует IList

```
'public static string Join(string delim, IList<string> values) '
```

а  group использует SortedSet

```
'using GroupedDevices = System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet<string>;'
```

Как исправить?

Comment: Попробуй так: `return StringHelper.Join(",",group.ToList());`

Comment: @Chloroform выдал такую ошибку >`System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet <string> 'не содержит определения для` ToList 'и не может быть найден метод расширения `ToList' типа` System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet <string> '. Вы пропускаете `System.Linq 'с помощью директивы?

Comment: так что же Вы? Не пропускайте!

Comment: @Igor добавил System.Linq.теперь ошибка вызов неоднозначен между следующими методами или свойствами: `System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList <string > (этот System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable <string>) 'и `System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList <string> (этот System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable <string>)'    И разве ToIList вместо ToList

Comment: Эээ? Неоднозначность между двумя одинаковыми методами? А можно [mcve]?

Comment: И кстати, почему не просто `string.Join(",", group)`?

Comment: @VladD Все заработало)Только не страшно,что так изменил?

Comment: @Андрей: Ну, я не знаю, что ваш `StringHelper` делает. Так что можно или нет заменять — решать вам.

Comment: @VladD StringHelper это класс.поэтому и страшно.вот      'public static class StringHelper {
  public static string Join(string delim, IList<string> values) 
  {
   
            if (values.Count == 1) {
                return values[0];
            }
            string ret = "";
            if (values.Count > 1) {
                for (int i = 0; i < values.Count - 1; ++i) {
                    ret += values[i] + delim;
                }
                // append last
                ret += values[values.Count - 1];
            }
            return ret;
        }'

Comment: @Андрей: Спокойно заменяйте. `StringHelper.Join` делает то же, что и `string.Join`, только гораздо менее эффективно.

Comment: @VladD Спасибо вам:)

Comment: @Андрей: Пожалуйста!